# Unhandled Exception System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, winapi

I have two project; a C++ library project and a C# windows application. Both are built in VS2008. Now I have to shift it to VS2012 but when I converted and run it; application crashes.

**Build Configuration:**

C++ Project: Win32

C# Project: x86

**Call Stack:**

> ntdll.dll!_ZwRaiseException@12()  + 0x12 bytes
>       ntdll.dll!*KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8()  + 0x2a bytes
>
>       KernelBase.dll!754ab727()
>
>       [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for KernelBase.dll]
>
>       mscorwks.dll!52fa7d1c()
>
>       mscorwks.dll!53010dfc()
>
>       mscorwks.dll!530bc9f0()
>
>       mscoreei.dll!720ff5a3()
>
>       KernelBase.dll!754b11c4()
>
>       mscoree.dll!72177efd()
>
>       mscoree.dll!72177f16()
>
>       mscoree.dll!72174de3()
>
>       kernel32.dll!751733ca()
>
>       ntdll.dll!*__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes
>       ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes

**Output:**

```
'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'D:\Source2\Source\Examples\Code     Samples\bin\x86\Debug\MyCSharpProject.exe', No native symbols in symbol file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_d08cc06a442b34fc\msvcr80.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Culture.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Culture.dll'
    'MyCSharpProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\62a0b3e4b40ec0e8c5cfaa0c8848e64a\mscorlib.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    'MyCSharpProject.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in Unknown Module.
    Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'MyCSharpProject.exe' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

Comment: Read the last line of the "output". It explains pretty clearly what's wrong.

Comment: You are still using an old version of .NET but trying to use an assembly that was built to target .NET 4.  This cannot work of course, change the target framework setting on your EXE project to .NET 4 as well.

Comment: I have re-build both projects in VS2012 with .net4.0.

Comment: The evidence you present in the question refutes that

Comment: How to get to know which is currently loaded runtime?